# What kingdom did pandavas have at the first place?

Tags: mahabharata

If kurukshetra war was to reclaim the lost kingdom of the pandavas then what was this kingdom which pandavas ruled before battle of kurukshetra?

Answer (score 1):

Pandavs did not have any kingdom before war.

When **Pandavs lost everything in चोसर** (gambling) and they were to condemned to **12 years of exile into forests** and a **13th year to be spent incognito**.

So **During the 12 years of exile** in the forest, **they prepared for war.**

Answer (score 1):

Yuddishthir was chakravartin samrat that means he was king of India and his capital was Indraprasth. He lost everything to Duryodhan in gambling.